# Гибридное управление памятью

Tags: память, любой-язык, сборщик-мусора

В каком языке программирования можно комбинировать ручное управление памятью (в нужный момент освободить, работа с указателями и так далее) и автоматическое, с достаточно продвинутым сборщиком мусора по поколениям?

Иными словами, нужны две отдельные кучи для работы с памятью.

Comment: C++ вам по каким то причинам не подходит ?

Comment: там есть сборщик мусора по поколениям?

Comment: c# /unsafe -- можно использовать указатели. см. msdn [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t2yzs44b.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вам подойдёт [C++/CLI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/68td296t.aspx). Это Microsoft'овский гибрид C++ и платформы .NET.

В нём .NET-объекты создаются при помощи `gcnew` и управляются сборщиком мусора, а стандартные C++-объекты создаются при помощи `new` и удаляются вручную через `delete`.